# Reaarranging excel data from matrix to row

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Month   Code     type  QTY   Price
201401  12345   AAA    20   76
201401  12345   BBB     6   1.57
201401  12345   DDD     1   4.5
201401  12345   EEE    417  8152
201401  12345   FFF    38   87
201401  12345   III     1   2
```

From the above cells I would get something like this

```
Month   Code    AAA_QTY    BBB_QTY   DDD_QTY  EEE_QTY  FFF_QTY  III_QTY   AAA_price    BBB_price   DDD_price   EEE_price  FFF_price  III_price   
201401  12345    20          6        1       417        38        1    76             1.57         4.5         8152       87         2
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: repeated the type.

Comment: I amkind of excel noob. I am trying to use if statements to compare but the logic is wrong.

Comment: Describe the logic of what you'd like to do in the question. So, for each month that's the same, and/or each code that's the same, move type.. etc

Comment: I had made some edits. you might find them helpful.

Comment: @Raystafarian http://i.imgur.com/dbQ1j8S.png will clarify some things.

Comment: Looks like you'll probably need a macro

Comment: Are you going to be developing a macro?  Or will you be using the manual method in the answer below?  If you want to develop a macro, post back showing where you are, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: I think pivot tables will be appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this dynamically but you can certainly do it manually.
Step 1) Copy / paste the `Month` and `Code` columns into, say, columns `G:H`
Step 2) Select columns `G:H` and click on `Remove Duplicates` in the `Data` ribbon
Step 3) More than likely, just click OK and let it filter the list for you
Step 4) Create your other column headings (if there's a big list, you might want to create the list somewhere else by copying the `Type` column, removing duplicates, paste special with transpose, etc.)
Step 5) In the first `XXX_QTY` field, use the following formula (for me, that cell is `I2`) (make sure the ranges are correct for your sheet):

```
=SUMIFS($D:$D,$A:$A,$G2,$B:$B,$H2,$C:$C,LEFT(I$1,3))
```

Step 6) The formula for the first `XXX_price` field is very similar (for me, that cell is `O2`):

```
=SUMIFS($E:$E,$A:$A,$G2,$B:$B,$H2,$C:$C,LEFT(O$1,3))
```

Step 7) Both of these formulas can be dragged over to cover the rest of the similar columns.

As you add new values to the data table, the formula table will update. However, if you add new month/code combinations, they will *not* be added automatically. There might be a way to do that but I bet it's messy and not worth it unless you expect to be doing this a lot.